# Is there a way to render PNG with gradients in Internet Explorer Mobile 7 correctly?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ie-mobile

Call me crazy, but I'm optimizing a website for the Internet Explorer Mobile 7. My main problem, besides several CSS issues, is that it seems that this browser displays 24 bit PNGs in 8 bit, that means gradients look horrible.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [dither](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) the image so that it renders nicely.

Here are two links that show you how to do this:

- [Photoshop action for Windows Phone 7 Dithering](http://nerdplusart.com/photoshop-action-for-windows-phone-7-dithering)
- [High Quality Dithering for Windows Phone 7](http://adtsai.blogspot.com/2011/03/high-quality-dithering-for-windows.html)