# Panorama Background Image is Blurry

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Panorama image in my app and when it loads on the phone it is blurry. It's like when you remote desktop into another computer and you have the color settings way down. The gradient is made up of 6 colors and I can count them from the big blocky change.

Is there something special that needs to be done for an image to work as a Panorama background?

I've tried using a JPG and PNG version of the image and it looks the same for either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 currently renders with 16bit color depth, unlike your desktop/emulator which has a higher color depth. As a result, gradients won't look the same as they do on your desktop PC.

This thread here has some great pointers on how to optimize your images for this environment:
[Is there a way to render PNG with gradients in Internet Explorer Mobile 7 correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596231/is-there-a-way-to-render-png-with-gradients-in-internet-explorer-mobile-7-correct)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Is there a place in the documentation that mentions this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but with Windows Phone Mango (7.5) you can now specify 32 bit by modifying your manifest.

```
BitsPerPixel="32"
```

Add that to the `<App xmlns="" ProductID="" BitsPerPixel="32"/>` and your images will now display in 32 bit mode.  You get a lot smoother gradients and color resolution.

The startup screen still is only 16 bit, and your icons will only really display in 16 bit.  But you can get nice colors in your app.