# PNG with gradients rendering

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use in my program PNG images with gradients. Images look fine in design mode on the computer, but on emulator and on device there is a incorrect rendering of gradient on PNG image (it looks like as picture of isotherms from school course of Geography).
Found this post about it: [Is there a way to render PNG with gradients in Internet Explorer Mobile 7 correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596231/is-there-a-way-to-render-png-with-gradients-in-internet-explorer-mobile-7-correc)
It works fine, but when I use DoubleAnimation for this image (I change an Opacity property of control from 0.0 to 1.0), gradient rendering bug appears again. It looks ugly, so is this possible to play DoubleAnimation of PNG image with gradients without these "isotherms"?

Thanks.

Comment: http://yeblon.com/fix-windows-phone-7-wp7-gradients-in-emulator-or-phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your application to use 32 bits per pixel. In your manifest file add the following:

```
BitsPerPixel="32"
```

See [this blog post](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2012/01/08/wp7-quick-tip-how-to-set-32-bits-per-pixel-for-your-app/) for an example.

Comment: Your suggestion works fine, but when image with gradient is animated above video, the render bug described above appears again. But by combining your suggestion and dithering image to 16 bit I have reached more or less acceptable results. If any, more beautiful solution is present, I will be glad to hear (or see) it :)

Comment: Also note devices are only required to have a 16-bit color display, so just setting this property will not work on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as @ColinE suggestion and set BitsPerPixel to 32bit, but be advised that this will require more memory and processing power from the phone, so more battery power will be drained!

Other way is to just dither your image to 16bit on Photoshop or some other app that has a palette dithering functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is useful too.